# Can the MAC address(es) of a Windows XP machine be found in a backup of C:\Documents and Settings\

Tags: windows-xp, mac-address

I recently had a Windows XP laptop stolen

I do not know its MAC addresses (wired or wireless)

I have managed to retrieve its wireless MAC from the WiFi router it was attached to, but I have no record of the wired MAC address.

I have a backup of the C:\Documents and Settings folder. Is there any way I can find the MAC address in there? As far as I can tell from Googling, the MAC address might exist in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE in the registry, but of course all I have in my backup are the NTUSER.DAT files corresponding to HKEY_CURRENT_USER for each user.

Comment: Was the laptop a DHCP client? If so, you could look in your DHCP server for the MAC address of the laptop from it's leased ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you were running a third-party application that stored MAC addresses in a file within the "Application Data" folder hierarchy I think you're out of luck. I'm not aware of any stock operating system functionality that would'be been storing MAC addresses in the "Documents and Settings" hierarchy.